# What is the negative index in shape arrays used for? (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

In the MNIST tutorial for Tensorflow, we reshape the output from the last Pool layer to a single vector. The code written was:

```
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
```

What is the -1 index for? Aren't we just trying to shape the output to a single vector, so why do we not just reshape to: [1, 7*7*64]?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

-1 means auto-expand. For example, a reshape with [-1, 7*7*64] will translate a 1-dimensional shape of, say, [19*7*7*64], to a 2-dimensional shape of [19, 7*7*64].

Another example, a reshape with [5, -1, 7] will translate a 1-dimensional shape of, say, [70], to a 3-dimensional shape of [5, 2, 7].

Comment: This is mainly for re adjust a tensor.  When ever tf sees -1 it will fit the data array or list in to desired shape.

Answer (score 7):

The -1 will be inferred.

So NumPy or TensorFlow will infer what the dimension size should be based on the incoming elements and the other dimensions specified

Comment: Just to build on this: the -1 is also an explicit way of telling TensorFlow that you *want* it to be inferred. It's also helpful as a human reading the code, since you know that the code author intended this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

First shape dimension of **-1** at input layer refer to **batch size** which may be variable.

E.g. we may have input shape of **(-1, 28, 28, 1)** which means we can input data (e.g. images) of size (28, 28, 1), that are received in **variable size of batches**. The batch size can be 32, or 128, or what so not and it will be automatically applied to the layer. It also works for other layers, e.g. output layer may also have shape of **(-1, 10)**, where first dimension also denotes variable batch size and it will be replaced with a correct batch size at a runtime.